# Array tridimensional con diferentes dimenesiones en Java

Tags: java, array, matrices

No sé si me explico pero, tengo este array:

```
int nMatrix = 3, row = 5, col = 2;
    String[][][] multimatrix = new String[nMatrix][row][col];
```

donde `nMatrix` serían las cantidades de matrices (por así decirlo para este ejercicio), y `row`, `col` serían las dimensiones para las filas y columnas de cada matriz, respectivamente.

Entonces, ¿existe forma de generar un array tridimensional donde cada una de las matrices pueda tener sus propias dimensiones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claro que puedes crear una matriz de diferentes dimensiones por cada `nMatrix`. Basta con que crees primero el espacio para almacenar las matrices y luego por cada espacio creas una matriz con la dimensión que necesites:

```
String[][][] multimatrix = new String[3][][]; //Espacio para 3 matrices
multimatrix[0] = new String[5][7]; //Primera matriz de 5x7
multimatrix[1] = new String[4][2]; //Segunda matriz de 4x2
multimatrix[2] = new String[9][5]; //Tercera matriz de 9x5
```

Incluso hasta podrías crear matrices con filas de diferentes dimensiones:

```
String[][][] multimatrix = new String[3][][]; //Espacio para 3 matrices
multimatrix[0] = new String[5][]; //Primera matriz de 5 filas con dimensiones no definidas.
multimatrix[0][0] = new String[2]; //Primera matriz, primera fila con 2 columnas.
multimatrix[0][1] = new String[5]; //Primera matriz, segunda fila con 5 columnas.
multimatrix[0][2] = new String[3]; //Primera matriz, tercera fila con 3 columnas.
multimatrix[0][3] = new String[1]; //Primera matriz, cuarta fila con 1 columna.
multimatrix[0][4] = new String[2]; //Primera matriz, quinta fila con 2 columnas.
...
```