# Saber el tamaño de un array tridimensional y llenarlo Java

Tags: java, array, matrices

Guiándome de la [solución](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/438158/array-tridimensional-con-diferentes-dimenesiones-en-java/438215#438215) que me dieron. Logré obtener mi array  tridimensional, donde las matrices tendrían la misma cantidad de filas, pero cada una tendría diferente columna.

```
 int nMatrix = 3, rows = 5;
    String[][][] matrix = new String[nMatrix][][];
    matrix[0] = new String[rows][r.nextInt(3) + 5];
    matrix[1] = new String[rows][r.nextInt(3) + 5];
    matrix[2] = new String[rows][r.nextInt(3) + 5];
```

Esa misma matriz la logro imprimir usando el siguiente código:

```
int cont = 0;
    String[] MatrixList = {"Matrix 1", "Matrix 2", "Matrix 3"};
    for (String[][] x : matrix) {
        System.out.println(MatrixList[cont++]);
        for (String[] y : x) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(y));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Arrojando las matrices vacías con sus respectivas dimensiones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi duda está en cómo podría averiguar el tamaño total de mi array (osea, cuántos elementos se les podría meter), ya que las columnas aleatorias de cada matriz me dificultan.

También quisiera saber cómo podría llenar(Por ejemplo, con números aleatorios) este tipo de array sabiendo la condición especial que tiene con las columnas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar la propiedad `length` para saber el tamaño de un array. Lo que quieres hacer lo puedes lograr así:

```
for (int z = 0; z < matrix.length; z++) {
    System.out.println("Matrix " + (z + 1));
    for (int y = 0; y < matrix[z].length; y++) {

        for (int x = 0; x < matrix[z][y].length; x++) {
            matrix[z][y][x] = ... //Almacena el valor aleatorio
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matrix[z][y]));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```